# How to use the output of attention wrapper applied over LSTM as an input to the TimeDistributed layer, Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, valueerror, attention-model

I have been trying to implement an attention wrapper over the output of the LSTM model shown in this [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/) tutorial:

```
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import LSTM
# prepare sequence
length = 5
seq = array([i/float(length) for i in range(length)])
X = seq.reshape(1, length, 1)
y = seq.reshape(1, length, 1)
# define LSTM configuration
n_neurons = length
n_batch = 1
n_epoch = 1000
# create LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(length, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
print(model.summary())
# train LSTM
model.fit(X, y, epochs=n_epoch, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=2)
# evaluate
result = model.predict(X, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=0)
for value in result[0,:,0]:
    print('%.1f' % value)
```

The output`(samples, steps, features)` of the LSTM with `return_sequences = true` is received by the attention wrapper (which outputs the shape (samples, features)). Here is my modified code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(length, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Attention())
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

I have been using the attention wrapper as described [here](https://gist.github.com/cbaziotis/6428df359af27d58078ca5ed9792bd6d):

```
    def dot_product(x, kernel):


        if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
            # todo: check that this is correct
            return K.squeeze(K.dot(x, K.expand_dims(kernel)), axis=-1)
        else:
            return K.dot(x, kernel)


class Attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self,
                 W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
                 bias=True, **kwargs):

        self.supports_masking = True
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')

        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)

        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)

        self.bias = bias
        super(Attention, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3

        self.W = self.add_weight((input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint)
        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight((input_shape[1],),
                                     initializer='zero',
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)
        else:
            self.b = None

        self.built = True

    def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
        # do not pass the mask to the next layers
        return None

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        eij = dot_product(x, self.W)

        if self.bias:
            eij += self.b

        eij = K.tanh(eij)

        a = K.exp(eij)

        # apply mask after the exp. will be re-normalized next
        if mask is not None:
            # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano
            a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())

        # in some cases especially in the early stages of training the sum may be almost zero
        # and this results in NaN's. A workaround is to add a very small positive number ε to the sum.
        # a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True), K.floatx())
        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())

        a = K.expand_dims(a)
        weighted_input = x * a
        return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]
```

However, the error I get is:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer time_distributed_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Is there any way out to readjust the shape of the attention wrapper's output so as to use the TimeDistributed layer?

Comment: get_output_shape_for should be compute_output_shape?.

Answer (score 2):

Use K.reshape or K.expand_dims to adjust the shape of the tensor returned in call(). TD layer expects three dimension and K.sum returns 2 dimension. You can either try K.expand_dims(a,axis=2), or K.reshape(a,shape=(-1,5,1) assuming a = K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1).

Comment: Could you please elaborate `weighted_input` ?

Comment: What the next layer is expecting is a sequence. You expand_dim 'a' to convert it to 3 dimension, and multiply it to W which should return you a sequence. But then, you sum it along axis = 1 which reduces it back to 2D. This is not what the next layer is expecting.  I did not notice expand_dim here.. which means instead of my suggestion above, you would simply pass the weighted_input to the TD layer directly.